# Can a whirlwind be moved in a straight line only?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The caster of a *[whirlwind](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/whirlwind)* spell can use a subsequent action to "move the whirlwind up to 30 feet in any direction along the ground." Is this up 30 feet in a straight line only? Or can the whirlwind move on a curve, or back and forth, potentially increasing the number of creatures that enter its space on this turn?

Comment: Are you asking about how the spell can be moved, or how often a creature can be affected?

Comment: @mdrichey That does help, I think. My initial read was that you were trying to bounce a creature in and out so that it would take damage multiple times on a turn.

Answer (score 1):

### No, you can move it in any direction

Spells do what they say, and the spell tells you that you can move the whirlwind 30' in any direction; it does not tell you that you have to move it in a straight line, nor that you can move it 30' but only in a single direction. There are no hidden rules. If you can move it so that it can hit more creatures by not following a straight line, you are permitted to do so.

This is also supported by the answer to: [When spells can be moved, must it be in a straight line?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/120142/75095)