# Can the Alarm spell affect an unseen area behind a barrier?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, area-of-effect

The [Alarm](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/alarm) spell in DnD 5e specifies:

> Choose a door, a window, or **an area within range** that is no larger
> than a 20-foot cube. Until the spell ends, an alarm alerts you
> whenever a tiny or larger creature touches or enters the warded area.

It does not specify that the caster should be able to see the target area (unlike many AOE spells).

Does this mean that it works through walls and doors to cover **any** 20'x20'x20' area I choose in range, irrespective of the structures within that area?

Comment: Could you please edit the title or the body to make them ask the same question? For now we can't answer "yes" or "no" to both "the spell have limits" and "the spell works through walls", which can be a source of confusion.

Comment: Updated question to the best I can manage; feel free to suggest an alternate if there's a better one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[A Clear Path to the target](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#AClearPathtotheTarget)

> To target something, you must have a clear path to it, so it can't be
> behind total cover. **If you place an area of effect at a point that you
> can't see and an obstruction, such as a wall, is between you and that
> point, the point of origin comes into being on the near side of that
> obstruction.**

[Areas of Effect](https://dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#AreasofEffect)

> Every area of effect has a point of origin, a location from which the
> spell's energy erupts.
>
> ...
>
> A spell's effect expands in straight lines from the point of origin.
> If no unblocked straight line extends from the point of origin to a
> location within the area of effect, that location isn't included in
> the spell's area.
>
> ...
>
> You select a cube's point of origin, which lies anywhere on a face of
> the cubic effect. The cube's size is expressed as the length of each
> side."

A diagram to illustrate
[image]

Comment: Hmmm. That's about targeting 'something'. Is an area a 'something', and if so, is it sufficient to see the edge of the area (in this case a wall or a door)? Specifically it says 'If you place an area of effect at a point that you can't see and an obstruction, such as a wall, is between you and that point, the point of origin comes into being on the near side of that obstruction.' and a cube can have a point of origin anywhere on any face.

Comment: @RabidMutant: https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#AreasofEffect "Every area of effect has a point of origin, a location from which the spell's energy erupts." ... "A spell's effect expands in straight lines from the point of origin. If no unblocked straight line extends from the point of origin to a location within the area of effect, that location isn't included in the spell's area." ... "You select a cube's point of origin, which lies anywhere on a face of the cubic effect. The cube's size is expressed as the length of each side."

Comment: Thanks! That does seem to cover it.

Comment: So...all of those spells that say "that you can see" are just wasting the ink?

Comment: @RabidMutant The intent is to remind people of the rules, this has caused some problems in the past with the helper text being read as additional rules, or people trying to use the existence of helper text on spell A to prove something about spell B. ‍♀️

Comment: A clear counterexample of targeted locations always needing a clear line of effect is the [*Clairvoyance*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/clairvoyance) spell, which can explicitly target locations up to a mile away (as long as they're familiar to you), or blocked from your view (such as the far side of a door).

Comment: So you must have a clear path to the point of origin, not the whole area. Therefore, some parts of the area *can* be behind a wall, etc. Is it correct?

Comment: @enkryptor Correct. Imagine you are shooting a fireball through the window of a house and it explodes inside hitting everything in the room - even though you can't see every part of the room's interior from where you are standing outside.

Comment: @Blckknght I'm not sure how to interpret Clairvoyance - maybe you really do need a clear line of sight. However the rules are crystal clear and explicit; "To target something, you must have a clear path to it".

Comment: @Non-humanPerson so the answer is actually "Yes" then? The spell *does* work through walls and doors.

Comment: By saying "No", did you mean an answer to "Does the Alarm spell have limits on the area affected" or the question body "Does this mean that it works through walls and doors"?

Comment: @enkryptor lol good point, I removed the "no" to let the text speak for itself and avoid confusion.

Comment: I think that this answer could be improve by adding some sentences explaining the rules and not just citing them, even if their application seems quite straightforward.

Comment: @Eddymage I'm not sure what more I could add. If you've got some ideas go ahead, I feel like I'd just be repeating the same thing again in different words.

Comment: "repeating the same thing again in different words": yep, that's an explanation! :-)

Comment: @Eddymage I'd rather not then, it seems clear to me and looks like OP is understands it! Best to let the rules speak for themselves whenever possible.

Comment: @Non-humanPerson I found a discussion that covers "that you can see" and why it is important, here https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62840/do-you-need-line-of-sight-to-cast-spells-on-someone ; the critical difference is that line-of-sight might exist but the target is not visible. So if it does not say "that you can see", then only an unobstructed path is needed (mist or magical darkness can be ignored).

Basic rule seems to be: unobstructed path ALWAYS required (unless explicitly excluded); visibility requirements depend on spell description.