# Does the Wall of Force spell block teleportation?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, teleportation, wall

Does the *Wall of Force* spell in 5e block teleportation? This does not seem to be addressed in the 5e spell description.

Answer (score 34):

No, *Wall of Force* does not block teleportation. The relevant parts of the spell description are:

> Nothing can physically pass through the wall.

This is pretty unambiguous, but teleporting isn't "physically passing" through the wall, so that's fine.

> The wall also extends into the Ethereal Plane,
>   blocking ethereal travel through the wall.

This is, admittedly, slightly less clear. However, there is nothing in the description of *Teleport* that suggests that it involves the *Ethereal Plane*. In fact, it doesn't really say anything about how it works:

> This spell instantly transports you [...]
>   to a destination you select.
>
> The destination you choose must be known to you,
>   and it must be on the same plane of existence as you.

That's all we know. However, there is much more compelling evidence in the description of *Forcecage*:

> If the creature tries to use teleportation or
>   interplanar travel to leave the cage, it must first make a
>   Charisma saving throw. On a success, the creature can use that magic to exit the cage. On a failure, the creature
>   can't exit the cage and wastes the use of the spell or
>   effect. The cage also extends into the Ethereal Plane,
>   blocking ethereal travel.

This is a pretty clear distinction between teleportation and ethereal travel (one is difficult, the other is actually impossible). So they are different, and the barrier to ethereal travel in *Wall of Force* does **not** apply to teleportation.

Comment: I guess you could say, being in a box and trying to teleport would mean you absolutely have to go through the box, but a wall cant really stop you from going in any direction the wall doesn't extend to, you know what I mean?

Comment: @Javelin: Description for the Wall Of Force: “You can form it into a hemispherical dome or sphere”

Comment: @Michael Ah, that's important. Breaks my whole line of thought there, and I don't want to cheese it with "it's magic". Darn!

Comment: thanks. I feel teleport works too. older definitions of WoF talk to teleport and dem door. I don't know why 5E dropped it from the definition.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Miniman's answer, it should be noted that any spell which targets a point (such as *misty step* ([depending on your interpretation of 'target'](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/152115))) will be blocked by a *wall of force*. Specifically:

> To target something, you must have **a clear path** to it, so it can't be behind **total cover**. If you place an area of effect at a point that you can't see and an obstruction, such as a wall, is between you and that point, the point of origin comes into being on the near side of that obstruction.

Emphasis mine. See other questions regarding the (debated) nature of cover.

Comment: You may wish to write your own answer to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/98905) if you believe *misty step* requires a clear path

Comment: Misty step's only requirement for designation is for the spot to be unoccupied and seeable. Wall of force by itself does nothing to hinder either condition. That's why you can misty step through windows.

Comment: I would note that [it's unclear whether the teleportation target for *misty step* is a 'target'](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/152115)—and that if it isn't, then you're indeed right.

Comment: @Clarus_Nox: But that's normal for most spells, and most spells can't be cast through total cover, including windows.  [Can spells be cast through a Wall of Force?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/132269) quotes a relevant Crawford tweet, that Wall of Force blocks spells in general by being total cover.