# Does Misty Step require line of effect to teleport you?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

This question stems from a question I asked about the targeting mechanic, [if line of effect is necessary](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/98826/is-it-legal-to-cast-a-spell-with-a-range-of-sight-on-someone-you-can-see-but-wi) to cast spells with a range of "Sight." The current (and only) answer discusses [it is not possible to target without line of effect](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/98828/27327), even if you can see the target.

Misty Step is generally known to pass through walls in this edition. As long as you can see the destination, you can appear in it. As the brief description of that spell states:

> Briefly surrounded by silvery mist, you teleport up to 30 feet to an unoccupied space that you can see.

Can Misty Step teleport you to the destination without line of effect?

Comment: Where are you getting the idea that *"Misty Step is generally known to pass through walls in this edition"* (I sure didn't know/think that) and how is this not just reasking you're previous question?

Comment: @PurpleMonkey It was my impression that that was known -- and you may show this is wrong via an answer if you want. The previous question is about spells with a range of "Sight" while this one is about a specific spell.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

*Misty Step* can indeed teleport without line of effect. *Misty Step* has:

> Range: Self

The target of the spell is yourself, which you (hopefully) always have a clear path to. The effect of the spell is to teleport you to a space you can see, but the space you can see is not a target of the spell and does not require a clear path.

Comment: Is *line of effect* a 5e term or an import from a previous edition?  I may have missed it the last time I was reviewing the spell section in PHB

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I think maybe you should write your own answer, as the changes you made in your edit form a completely different answer to the one I gave.

Comment: @Miniman You may want to add that while a clear path isn't necessary, you still need to be able to see your destination to clarify Markovchain's "generally known to pass through walls" statement.

Comment: @NautArch "The effect of the spell is to teleport you to a space you can see"

Comment: I know, but given the specific statement by Markovchain I thought it might be worth it to call that out as something you can't really do.