# Where do you end up when you cast Dimension Door from an extradimensional space?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, teleportation, extradimensional-space, portals

There are a number of limited, extradimensional spaces, for example the ones created by *demiplane*, a *bag of holding*, or a *portable hole*.

Say you are in a closed *portable hole*,  *bag of holding* or *demiplane*, and cast "Dimension Door, 100 feet straight ahead", what happens? Would it make a difference if the door on the demiplane was still there, or the hole or bag were open?

Comment: Related: [What does "spot" mean when casting a spell](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/101225/what-does-spot-mean-when-casting-a-spell)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The spell would fail

Any teleportation spell needs to be aimed at a valid target, just like any other spell. In our case, a "valid target" is an empty space that respects the spell's conditions.

In the case of a demiplane or any other plane limited in size, the area "outside" of those boundaries does not exist. Because of that, there is no empty space (or, for that matter, any place at all) that could be targeted by the spell. Just like if you tried using a spell on a target that is not valid, your spell will simply fail to take effect.

In a practical situation, your DM would probably tell you beforehand so you don't waste a spell slot, though.

#### So, do I take force damage?

The spell *Dimension Door* states the following :

> If you would arrive in a place already occupied by an object or a creature, you and any creature traveling with you each take 4d6 force damage, and the spell fails to teleport you.

If you do try to cast the spell outside of a demiplane, you do not target a place that's occupied by "an object or a creature". So even if you decided to cast the spell, according to the rules as written, it shouldn't inflict the force damage.

#### What about a *bag of holding* ?

The inside part of a *bag of holding* is considered as a separate plane, very similar to the demiplane we just talked about. This means you shouldn't be able to leave it with a spell that does not authorize cross-plane travel.

Do note that even if you did use such a spell, you'd have to target the plane where the bag is located, and not the space beyond the "demiplane's" boundaries. The plane is not inside the bag, the bag's entrance is merely acting as a portal.

The same is true for a *portable hole*, since it's even more obvious that it acts as a portal to another plane, rather than a magically-larger container.

#### And if I target through the opening?

It's up to the DM and how they want to work with gates/portals. [Dale M's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/200418/77044) and the questions linked to that answer cover this topic very well.

Comment: What about a bag of holding? If it is open you can probably physically see the target. Would that fail?

Comment: @SeriousBri I'll edit my post to answer that.

Answer (score 6):

### Planes are infinitely far apart and Dimension Door's 500 feet limit is less than that

See [Can I message from an extradimensional space? What is the distance?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/198195/can-i-message-from-an-extradimensional-space-what-is-the-distance/198197#198197)

If the bag was open, the DM would need to decide if the opening reduces the range to 0 or if it allows transport between planes but they are still infinitely far apart. See [What is the distance to points in another dimension, if there is a portal or gate to it?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/198226/what-is-the-distance-to-points-in-another-dimension-if-there-is-a-portal-or-gat)

If the former then DD should work fine the limit in the spell is "any other spot within range" and it doesn't care if that spot is on another plane. If the latter, then it's still out of range.