# Does the Eyebite Spell Work Through a Wall of Force?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting, cover, line-of-effect

Does the [Eyebite](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/eyebite) spell work through a [Wall of Force](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wall-of-force)? Or is it blocked by Full Cover, even if the target can be seen?

This question is similar [to this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/132122/do-gaze-effects-work-through-a-wall-of-force), but contrarily to Gaze effects the spell Eyebite obeys the following rule regarding spell casting:

> To target something, you must have a clear path to it, so it can’t be behind total cover.

Comment: Related: [Can spells be cast through a Wall of Force?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59734/can-spells-be-cast-through-a-wall-of-force), [How does Wall of Force grant cover?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/132265/how-does-wall-of-force-grant-cover)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In general, 5e rulings are adjudicated first by following exactly what is written, and second (if what is written is unclear or silent on the subject in question) by the GM. So, my answer is:

## Yes, but...

This GM would rule that yes an *eyebite* spell could affect through a *wall of force* (*WoF*). The [*WoF* spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wall-of-force) says that it protects (or, traps) like so (emphasis mine):

> Nothing can *physically pass through the wall*. It is immune to all
>   damage and can't be dispelled by dispel magic. A disintegrate spell
>   destroys the wall instantly, however. The wall also extends into the
>   Ethereal Plane, blocking ethereal travel through the wall.

The [*eyebite* spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/eyebite) reads like so (emphasis my own):

> For the spell's duration, your eyes become an inky void imbued with
>   dread power. One creature of your choice within 60 feet of you *that
>   you can see* must succeed on a Wisdom saving throw or be affected...

*Eyebite* simply requires that the victim be seen but not interacted with in any other way. Since *WoF* is a transparent barrier, it can be seen through, thus *eyebite* works.

### However...

With that ruling, this GM might end up on an unraveling, or nerfing, of the *WoF* spell. [This previous discussion](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59734/can-spells-be-cast-through-a-wall-of-force) explains that a *WoF* blocks **all spells** by creating total cover. Simply put, a creature within the *WoF* cannot be the *target* of a spell. Ah, you say, but *eyebite*'s target is "self"--too true! The victim of the *eyebite* spell must then be merely "seen" (not "gazed") and, we wind up back at my ruling above that transparent walls can be seen through and thus, the *eyebite* spell works through *WoF*.

**So it comes down to this:** The GM needs to rule whether or not "seeing" the victim of the *eyebite* spell counts as targeting for the purposes of cover.

Comment: "In 5e rulings are adjudicated first by following exactly what is written, and second (if what is written is unclear or silent on the subject in question) by the GM." In general this statement is only true for RAW interpretations which is not the only type of ruling there is.

Comment: I’ll edit to accommodate :)

Comment: You make a strong argument that the spell _should_ affect someone on the other side of a wall of force, but at the end I can't tell if that's actually your answer.

Comment: @MarkWells the answer is "ask your DM because here is 2 different rulings I can come up with"

Comment: @SaggingRufus They're the same ruling, though. "Since WoF is a transparent barrier, it can be seen through, thus eyebite works." And then: "The victim of the eyebite spell must then be merely "seen" (not "gazed") and, we wind up back at my ruling above that transparent walls can be seen through and thus, the eyebite spell works through WoF."

Comment: The second ruling, by my own logic comes back around to my own judgement, but it really comes down to the GM and how they view “seen” and total cover.

Comment: @TigerDM The spell directly targets a creature here, thus total cover blocks it. Targets specified in a spells description are still targets. Going by your logic, lightning bolt doesnt have multiple targets

Answer (score -1):

No

spells require a clear path to the target. Any form of total cover prevents that. thus you cant do it

cover states

> A target with total cover can't be targeted directly by an attack or a
> spell, although some spells can reach such a target by including it in
> an area of effect. A target has total cover if it is completely
> concealed by an obstacle.

A creature inside a wall of force has total cover thus it cant be targeted

Its the same reason you cant cast hold person on a person behind a closed window, or why you cant directly target a creature inside a glass dome with firebolt. Whether the creature is visible isnt relevant here