# Can you summon a spiritual weapon into the bubble created by Bead of Force? Can whoever is inside cast charm person on someone outside the bubble?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting, line-of-sight, line-of-effect

The wording for Bead of Force says "Only breathable air can pass through the sphere's wall. No Attack or other Effect can." which obviously means that spells such as firebolt or ray of sickness could not harm a creature inside. However, what about spells that only require line of sight?

I've read the [discourse](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59734/can-spells-be-cast-through-a-wall-of-force) on Wall of Force, which suggests that you would not be able to do such spells, and the wording is similar to Bead of Force.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: I have closed your question as I felt it was effectively identical to the *wall of force* one. Both effects state nothing can pass through them so they feel effectively identical to me ("Nothing can physically pass through the wall" vs "Only breathable air can pass through the sphere's wall"). Is there anything particular to a Bead Of Force that you think makes it a separate question?

Comment: @Medix2 I'm not sure it's a duplicate. The Beads don't reference *wall of force*, so It' similar, maybe even identical, but because they are different I don't think it's a dupe.