# Can a creature see through a Wall of Force if See Invisibility is cast on them?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, invisibility, line-of-sight

The text for Wall of Force says (emphasis mine):

> An **Invisible** wall of force springs into existence at a point you choose within range. [...]

The text for See Invisibility says (emphasis mine):

> For the duration, you see **invisible** creatures and **objects as if they were visible** [...]

So could a creature with See Invisibility see through the Wall of Force or would it block sight?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have seen this heavily debated in the past.

The general consesus is usually, that it depends on the DM.

As for line of sight rules about "Wall of force", you might want to take a look at this answer from another post:

https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/132269

Basically for the sake of for example spells, the wall gives total cover anyway, which means it would make people behind it untargettable, thus sort of breaking line of sight (akin to the age old debate over glass windows)

Something you'll have to think about is the following:

> For the duration, you see invisible creatures and objects **as if they were visible**, and you can see into the Ethereal Plane.
> Ethereal creatures and objects appear ghostly and translucent.

This means, you'll see the wall **as it would appear if it weren't invisible**.

The question is, what does the wall look like? The name suggest it is compromised of pure 'force', whatever that may be. One might even be inclined to think of it as etheral, which would make it seem translucent.

If I were to rule this exact situation, the wall would appear translucent, but would block line of sight effects, since that is a big part of the Spells use after all. But again, take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: We typically distinguish between "line of sight" and "line of effect" in order to make it clearer which concept we are referring to. A solid but see-through thing (such as a window or wall of force) blocks line of effect but not line of sight. Line of effect is the thing that nearly all spells require (phrased in the PHB as "a clear path to the target"). Many *also* require line of sight; a few exceptions require neither.

Comment: +1 for the additional comment. It's always finnicky to rule about such things. If it is a spell, it is almost always clear. But things like feats/class features and whatnot may (in a lot of cases) not apply to this. If you are ever in such a case, you'll have to discuss it with your Dm, if the wall is translucent, or opaque.

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson  Great comment.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to give the other answer using a different interpretation. No, you cannot see the invisible wall of force after casting see invisibility. The wall of force is invisible by an intrinsic feature, not a magical effect. Air is also invisible intrinsically, but you do not become surrounded by a thick opaque fog after casting see invisibility, eh?

Comment: Fun fact, air is not invisible (you can see distortions due to temperature after all). Rather, it has such a low density of actual matter, that you do not perceive any visual blockage from it. A Wall of Force is explicitly not matter, rather it is energy(or, well, force). This would lead me to agree with this answer except for the invisible air bit.

Comment: "Do not perceive any visual blockage from it" is another way of saying invisible, in my book. Also, a particle too small to be seen could be called invisible, even if magnification renders it visible. Invisible is just a word that literally means "not-visible", not whatever magic connotation you have associated with it. Distortions in the air due to heat render it partially visible. When these are not present it's invisible.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, people are being way too literal about this. The Wall of Force is invisible to normal sight. You might have to run into it or see an arrow bounce off to realize that it even existed. And, even then, you would not necessarily understand its extents.

If you can “see invisible,” either by natural ability or spell, then you can perceive the wall. But there is no logic in assuming that you are unable to control that extra visual capability to perceive the Wall of Force, to perceive what is behind the Wall of Force, or possibly even a combination of the two like looking through a translucent curtain. The ability to see invisible things should be treated as an advantage, not a liability.

If I were DM’ing a situation like that, I would treat it in that manner.

Comment: you cannot decide to 'unsee' invisible things once you have the spell effect on you.  you will see the wall for what it is.  the it is DM decision to determine if a wall of pure force is opaque or not.  if it is.  then you cannot see what is behind it.

Answer (score 1):

You would see the wall for  what it is.

Then it would be DM interpretation to determine if a wall of pure force is opaque or not to you.   If it is opaque you cannot see through it,  if it is not then it is like a glass wall and you can see throught it.

But whether you see throught it or not, all spell effects and attacks are blocked as you do not have line of effect.