# Can you Misty Step past a Wall of Force?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, teleportation

A Wall of Force is [invisible](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Wall%20of%20Force#content). Misty Step allows you to

> Teleport up to 30 feet to an unoccupied space that you can see.

Can you Misty Step past a Wall of Force?

Comment: Heavily related: [Can spells be cast through a Wall of Force?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/59734/41726)

Comment: The [How do I ask a good question?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) help article asks "Have you [thoroughly searched for an answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search) before asking your question?". While not all of your duplicate closed questions have been easy to find in the search results, one or two of them were probably easy to find with a little bit of preliminary research. I would recommend spending a little bit of extra time searching around the site before asking a question.